# Is there a way to disable firebase analytics with a scheme argument in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to disable firebase analytics from collecting & sending events when I'm building, testing & debugging via an Xcode scheme argument, if able.

I'm aware you can edit the info.plist to disable ([Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios#temporarily_disable_collection_1)) but would prefer a solution that doesn't require me to edit the .plist every time I'd like to switch between enabled and disabled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I came up with is very similar to Paul Beusterien's answer, but doesn't require a seperate scheme.

I made a copy of my current `info.plist` and named it `info-debug.plist`. I added the required key and value to disable firebase analytics.

> FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED = 0

[image: info-debug screenshot]

Then I selected my scheme `Testing` and under `Packing` -> `Info.plist File` -> `Debug` I set the value to `info-debug.plist`

[image: build settings screenshot]

Anytime I build and run my app in Xcode it will use `info-debug.plist` because my `Build Configuration` is set to the default: `Debug`. When I archive my app it will use `info.plist` as set by the `Build Configuration` for `Release`.

> https://medium.com/geekculture/what-are-debug-and-release-modes-in-xcode-how-to-check-app-is-running-in-debug-mode-8dadad6a3428
>
> **Debug vs Release Mode**
>
> When you create a new project in Xcode, it defines two build
> configurations, Debug and Release. By default, Debug configuration is
> used during development whereas the Release configuration is used for
> TestFlights or App Store. In other words, when you run the app on the
> simulators or real devices by hitting the Run button(cmd + R), your
> app is running with Debug configuration, aka Debug mode; when you
> archive and upload a build to App Store Connect, app is running in
> Release mode. However, this is just the default behavior. Technically,
> you can run apps on simulators in any mode you want. It’s also true
> for archiving(builds that you upload to the App Store Connect). To
> change build configurations for development and archiving, you can go
> to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme(Command + <):
> [image: scheme screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure two different plists into two different build targets, each with an associated scheme.

Details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_apple_application).